# using two edittexts

Tags: android, android-edittext

here is my question, I am designing an application, I am using two Edit Texts and Buttons, so when I use a input filter with a maximum length of 4 and set the focus to the other Edit Texts, when I write, the focus pass to the second Edit Text, but it does not write en I input something instead it keep writing in the first one.

is there a way to only put 4 character in the first Edit Text stop writing in it, and then write in the second without altering the first thank you.

here is the part of the code of my problem:

```
String inDigit = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
//Costo de venta
if (inStr.equals("0")) {
    inStr = inDigit; 
} else {
inStr += inDigit; 
}
int maxLength = 4;
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
editX.setFilters(FilterArray);
editX.setText(inStr);

if(editX.getText().toString().length() == 4)
{
    if(editX.hasFocus()){
        editY.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    }else {
        editY.getText().toString();
        editY.setText("");
    }

    if (lastOperator == '=') {
        result = 0;
        lastOperator = ' ';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to only put 4 character in the first Edit Text stop writing in it, and then write in the second without altering the first

Yes. Let's assume that you have that the first EditText is called `edit` to the second is a class variable `edit2`. We'll use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to switch focus from `edit` to `edit2` once you exceed the fourth character:

```
edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length() == 4) {
            edit2.requestFocus();
        }
    }
});
```